# problem with django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have the following django form . which has a choice field. im trying to get the value selected in the `radioSelect` widget . im using (cleaned_data) method for this task.
but it cant access the method cleaned_data for some reason.

Exception Value :`'AnswersForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'`

forms.py:

```
class AnswersForm(forms.Form):

        CHOICES=[('sf','asdf')]
        answers = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

and in views.py:

```
    form = forms.AnswersForm()
    form.cleaned_data['answers']
```

does anyone know what is going on ? or is there another way to perform this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show any code where you pass data to the form or check if it is valid. Normal practice is something like:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Forms.AnswersForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        do_something_with(form.cleaned_data['answers'])
```

**You cannot access `cleaned_data` until you call `is_valid()`**

Comment: +1 you can only access the cleaned_data after the form has been validated

Answer (score 0):

Use `Form.clean()` It just returns `self.cleaned_data`

**Note:**
Clean the data in the `forms.py`

```
def clean(self,):
  Here you can clean the form.
```

**For Reference **  [Go Here (Django doc)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

Comment: `Form.clean()` is there so you can augment the normal clean functionality, which is used internally when you call `.valid()`. The question doesn't seem to be about form validation but rather about just accessing the cleaned_data. calling `clean()` is not the way to do it.